# Why is the function $f(x,y)=x^y$ not associative?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I wonder why the function $f(x,y)=x^y$ isn't associative (according to my book)?
My answer was:

The function is associative if $f(x,f(y,z) = f(x,f(y,z))$

$f(f(x,y),z) = f(x,y)^z = x^{{y}^{z}}$

$f(x,f(y,z)) = x^{f(y,z)} = x^{y^z}$

Thus, $f(x,f(y,z) = f(x,f(y,z))$ and therefore the function is associative.

Comment: **Hint :** $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ has no reason to be equal to $x^{\left(y^z\right)}$.

Comment: $f(f(2,3),2)=f(8,2)=64\neq f(2,f(3,2))=f(2,9)=512$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first equalities are wrong. You should have
$$f(f(x,y),z)=f(x^y,z)=(x^y)^z=x^{yz};$$
when we have something like $x^{y^z}$, this means $x^{(y^z)}$, which is distinct from $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$3^{(3^3)}= 3^{27} > (3^3)^3 = 27^3$$